# Can't find problem with YAML parse exception

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I tried to build my book with R Bookdown and it runs smoothly to the end and gives me this error then:

YAML parse exception at line 4, column 20:
mapping values are not allowed in this context
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 64

It seems not to be a problem with my YAML in the index file

```
---
title: "xxx"
author: "Moiken E. Hinrichs"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d.%m.%Y')`"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize}
   - \captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize}
   - \usepackage{subfig}
   - \usepackage{footmisc}
   - \usepackage{float}
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
     extra_dependencies: ["flafter"]
classoption: twoside
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: references.json
documentclass: book
bookdown::pdf_book:
  toc_depth: 3
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  csl: "taylor-and-francis-harvard-v.csl"
  keep_tex: yes
  link-citations: yes
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---
```

I tried deleting the fourth line, and I still get the same error for the same line and column. I know there a some more YAML files in Bookdown, but I haven't touched them. So the bookdown.ylm says:

```
delete_merged_file: true
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "
```

and the output.yml:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">A Minimal Book Example</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit: https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/edit/BRANCH/%s
    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

Does anybody have a suggestion what is causing trouble here?
Rstudio and R are up to date and so are all the packages needed.

Comment: In the first YAML, you have two specifications for output (`output:...` and `bookdown::pdf_book`). I think the later should be an indent of the former.